# How to make round buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I make round buttons using HTML and CSS? I tried to use a background image, and make it a certain size, but that doesn't seem to work. Specifically, I would like to make a circular button, which on a click would launch a Javascript script.

Answer (score 23):

With `border-radius`:

```css
button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('you done clicked the button')">Clicky</button>
```

Comment: Which browsers? Could you be specific?

Comment: It's probably better to use border-radius; 50%; instead of hardcoding it in pixels. That way you can change dimensions without thinking about the border radius. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BfjAK/2/

Comment: information on border-radius browser support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t45

Comment: You can add `-moz-border-radius: 50px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 50px;` to support older mozilla and webkit browsers

Comment: @BryanWeaver That information is outdated. Use [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) for info on browser-support.

Comment: Hope you can accept this answer no? @Andrew Alexander

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite simply with CSS3:

```css
#button {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

And use an onclicked event to make it a button.

Comment: `border-radius: 50%;` should do. Also the markup can be `<button>Click
Me</button>`, while the css is `button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}`

Answer (score -2):

border-radius need not be a percentage.  Try setting it in pixels instead.

Comment: There is no `border-radius` in the question. If you are referring to other answers, use comments under those answers.